# Material-UI: issues with dropdown (Select control) inside a Dialog

Tags: material-ui

Just wondering if anyone has seen issues using a dropdown list (Select control) inside a Dialog control.  When I change the selection in the dropdown list I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null
    at ariaHidden (manageAriaHidden.js:28)
    at ModalManager.remove (ModalManager.js:188)
    at Modal._this.handleClose (Modal.js:145)
    at Modal.componentDidUpdate (Modal.js:221)
    at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:14693)
    at commitAllLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:15905)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:145)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:195)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:248)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:16075)
    at completeRoot (react-dom.development.js:17463)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:17391)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:17295)
    at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:17267)
    at interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:17558)
    at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2208)
    at dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.development.js:4913)
```

The same exact code is working when not inside a Dialog so just wondering if this is something that isn't allowed/suggested.  The error points to ModalManager so it does seem related to being inside the Dialog.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Hold on, I did search for a similar issue before posting but now just stumbled on one that looks the same (https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13349).  Let me try upgrading first.  Sorry for the possible duplicate!

Comment: Still an issue after upgrading to 3.3.1 but looks like they are on it (https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13365)

Comment: Have you tried downgrading to 3.2.2, as suggested in the github issue? Maybe it is just a regression in the newest version. I'm using material-ui v3.0.1 and `Select` inside `Dialog` works fine.

Comment: Just tried that expecting it'd work based on other's comments but no such luck unfortunately.  It's not critical right now so I'll wait on the fix since it looks like they are aware of the issue and working on it.